# Equivalent of Guava's Strings.isNullOrEmpty() for Long, Integer, etc

Tags: java, guava

Is there something like .isNullOrZero() in util libs like Guava for java boxed numeric primitive types?

Comment: That question is too vague; for one, you do not even tell about your use case. Some sample code please?

Comment: What is wrong with `x == null || x == 0`?

Comment: @kostya it's just longer to write, especially if x is a variable with a long name. Guava/StringUtils has Strings.isNullOrEmpty() but there is nothing like this for numeric types

Comment: There is a good reason for it. I don't think there are many programs where `isNullOrZero` check is very useful. An empty string (usually coming as input to a program) almost always means missing value. `0` on other hand is a valid value for Long or Integer, in almost all cases it is not the same as missing value.

Comment: @kostya got it thanks

Comment: `MoreObjects.firstNonNull(obj, default)`. There is no special case for primitives as a value like 0 is a magic number.

Comment: Just get rid of `null` ASAP (use `firstNonNull` as Ben Manes wrote).

Answer (score 1):

A Integer, Long can not be empty if it is not `null`; it can be zero in this case. So for Integer or Long you can write something like this -

```
public static boolean isNullOrZero( final Object obj) {

   if(null == obj) return true;

   if( obj instanceof Integer ){
      Integer i = (Integer) obj;
      return (i == 0);
   } 

   if( obj instanceof Long ){
      Long l = (Long) obj;
      return (l == 0);
   } 
}
```

For Collection, if it is not null then it can be empty. Then you can write your own `isNullOrEmpty()` method like this -

```
public static boolean isNullOrEmpty( final Collection< ? > collection ) {
    return (collection == null || collection.isEmpty() );
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Razib, I understand this. I'm just curious, why this method is not presented in Google/Apache utils libraries along with String.isNullOrEmpty(). Would isNullOrZero() lead to unreadable code or encourage bad coding style?

Comment: This code is not a very good example of Java code: no types, unnecessary ternary operator

Comment: @Tom, why.? Just want to know, though I haven't tried to compile it.

Comment: @kostya, I think the ternary operator is required here. Otherwise if it is not zero then how can we return `false`. May be we can use an `if-esle` here but ternary operator is just an replacement of `if-esle`, I think. Or am doing something wrong?

Comment: @Razib "though I haven't tried to compile it." Then do that and then ask if you still have a question.

Comment: @Razib, `return i == 0` is the same as `return i == 0 ? true : false`

Comment: @Razib About your ternary operator: You know what you're currently doing there, right? Something like this: `return (if true ? true : false)`. `i == 0` is a boolean expression which either returns `true` or `false`, so there is no point in checking if it returned true, just to return true "manually", or false otherwise. You can replace each of you ternary with `return i == 0;`.

Comment: Oh! thanks, what a fool I am! :( . I have just update it. Thanks both kostya and Tom

Comment: Then there remains only one thing: compile your code :).

Comment: @user3439496, "why this method is not presented in Google/Apache utils" is a very subjective question; that said, I have two ideas. (1) For most applications, `null` and the empty String may be treated equivalently, but for most applications `null` and 0 should not be. (2) We should [avoid supporting null in our APIs](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=134) because null is a meaningless, nonsense value, and the right response is a `NullPointerException`. In code reviews, I often tell developers to *remove* their `if (var != null)` checks and replace them with exceptions.